# How to speedup python venv caching in GitLab CI local runner?

Tags: gitlab-ci, cicd, gitlab-runner

On trying to cache a venv folder for python job in shell executor, it seems slower than without caching. I am using multiple local runners. Can I use NFS for creating a shared folder and make cache path to same for speeding up? Any alternative solutions?

config.toml

```
[[runners]]
  name = "shell_runner1"
  url = "https://gitlab.abc.in/"
  token = "xyz"
  executor = "shell"
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
   PIP_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache/pip"
cache:
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - venv/
```

Answer (score 1):

After trial and errors, I figured that NFS sharing home/gitlab-runner/.cache doesnt help in case of venv (large folder), maybe good for artifacts. Its better to not remove venv folder than adding venv to cache, jobs are faster now.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: -ffdx -e venv/
# cache:
#   paths:
#     - venv/
```

Comment: You have the only one step that install and no pre_script ?